# How to do a looping from setter getter in android?

Tags: java, android, loops, getter-setter

I've made a setter getter in Array List, and I want to show them up in my activity.

This is my code

```
   response = (ProductListResponse) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("response");
        category = response.getListCategory();
        list = response.getListCategory().get(0).getProductList();
```

from `get(0)` , i only got index 0 from my response. So, How to get the all index? thank you

Comment: still if you don't getting solution then please post your json response here.i will print arraylist from json response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use for loop for that like this

```
for(int i=0;i<response.getListCategory().size();i++){
list = response.getListCategory().get(i).getProductList();; // use list
}
```

or you can use `foreach`

```
for(datamodel data:response.getListCategory()){
list=data.getProductList(); //use the list
}
```